# Creating A GitHub Action to publish to DockerHub with the current release tag

Tags: docker, github, github-actions, dockerhub

I'd like to have the following workflow:

- Draft a new Release on GitHub
- Add a release tag in the format `YY.MM.DD`
- Publish the release

What Should happen is

- A release is created with the mentioned release tag in the format `YY.MM.DD`
- The release on GitHub is tagged as `latest` and `YY.MM.DD`
- A docker image is created and published to DockerHub
- The docker image on DockerHub contains tags `latest`, the current sha and the release tag in the format `YY.MM.DD`

Currently I have this workflow which publishes a new release and image to DockerHub, but what I'm missing is:

- The release on GitHub is NOT tagged as `latest`
- The docker image on DockerHub does NOT contain the release tag in the format `YY.MM.DD`

Any help would be appreciated!

```
# This workflow uses actions that are not certified by GitHub.
# They are provided by a third-party and are governed by
# separate terms of service, privacy policy, and support
# documentation.

# GitHub recommends pinning actions to a commit SHA.
# To get a newer version, you will need to update the SHA.
# You can also reference a tag or branch, but the action may change without warning.

name: Publish Docker image

on:
  release:
    types: [published]

jobs:
  docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Set up dynamic build ARGs
        id: getargs        
        run: echo "version=$(cat ./stable/VERSION)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - name: Docker meta
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v3
        with:
          # list of Docker images to use as base name for tags
          images: |
            jokobsk/pi.alert
          # generate Docker tags based on the following events/attributes
          tags: |
            type=raw,value=latest
            type=schedule
            type=ref,event=branch
            type=ref,event=pr
            type=semver,pattern={{version}}
            type=semver,pattern={{major}}.{{minor}}
            type=semver,pattern={{major}}
            type=sha
      - name: Login to DockerHub
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          context: .
          platforms: linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm/v7
          push: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
```

Comment: What is the published `tag` and `date` that is pushed to DockerHub?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for reading! Here are some relevant screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/XpCOg6w.png https://i.imgur.com/bkeQ1JM.png

Comment: IIUC, that semver is invalid for DockerHub but it is valid for GHCR, right? And, the `latest` tag is being pushed to DockerHub but not to GHCR?

Comment: Yes, I think your assessment is correct, I'm pretty new when it comes to tags and releases though...

Comment: I think you can have two separate meta steps e.g. `meta-docker` and `meta-ghcr` and assign only those tags that the respective container registry supports.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but could you be a bit more concrete? My CI/CD knowledge is pretty basic. Thanks in advance and apologies to be  a pain!

Answer (score 0):

please check this:

https://blog.derlin.ch/github-actions-reusable-workflow-docker-images

> As a bonus, I wanted to be able to also push to Docker Hub, but only in specific situations (e.g. from a release, but not from a PR build) and with a different set of tags (no main-{sha}).
> This conditionality was a bummer, as it is not supported by default. After playing around a bit, I designed a hack to implement this "if" without duplicating the whole workflow.
> If you are interested, have a look at the updated workflow: https://github.com/derlin/rickroller/blob/e67546a90218c8300676c1270699cccdb5f7e053/.github/workflows/reusable_docker-build-and-push.yaml and let me know in the comments if you would like a post about it!

Hope it helps.
Filipe Nascimento

Comment: Looks promising, will give it a try and update here if it worked

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be better if you could extract the meaningful relevant bits out of the linked YAML file and post them here directly. This helps searchability and also protects against the repository becoming unreachable. Thanks!